# Spark Sql query works with hardcoded value but not with variable

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark program in which there is a SQL query like this:

```
id = 'abc1'

info = sqlc.sql("SELECT * from df WHERE isn = 'id'")
```

This query does not work. I am returned with a blank set of values. However, if I hardcode the value, it works.

```
info = sqlc.sql("SELECT * from df WHERE isn = 'abc1'")
```

I have tried `str(id)` just to be sure. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use format in Python 3.5 or before:

```
info = sqlc.sql("SELECT * from df WHERE isn = '{id}'".format(id=id))
```

or

```
info = sqlc.sql("SELECT * from df WHERE isn = '{}'".format(id))
```

Literal string formatting in Python 3.6 and later:

```
info = sqlc.sql(f"SELECT * from df WHERE isn = '{id}'")
```